# Feature importance using logistic regression in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, logistic-regression

I am using logistic regression in PySpark. I have after splitting train and test dataset

```
LR = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'label', maxIter=some_iter)
LR_model = LR.fit(train)
```

I displayed `LR_model.coefficientMatrix` but I get a huge matrix. Is there a routine to select the important features and get the name of their related columns ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Figuring out which features correspond to what columns? Facing the exact same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I create a package called [spark_ml_utils](https://github.com/xinyongtian/py_spark_ml_utils). The function feature_importance() in module spark_ml_utils.LogisticRegressionModel_util performs the task.